# HTML form file upload does not work, $_POST does not forwards data

Tags: php, html, forms, file, input

Maybe it is just too early here, but can't figure out the problem... I have made several forms already, but this time for a reason I can't forward the data of my file input.

Here is my **index.php** (where the form is):

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file1">
<input type="submit" name="order">
</form>
```

Here is my confirm.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['order'])) {

    $file       = $_POST['file1'];

    echo $file;

}
?>
```

And I get the following error message:

**Notice:** Undefined index: file1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.../confirm.php on line 4

I seriously don't understand what is the problem. This is a rock easy form and I think it is correct. Can you please help me with this huge issue? :DD Btw. the form proceeds **all the other input data except the file.**

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: You access files through $_FILES not post. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your input type is file so you can not access by `$_POST`

```
`type="file"` // Not Accessible through `$_POST`
```

Php is providing separate http group `$_FILES` for getting the value of input which type should be `file` like this `type="file"`

So you can you get the input value by `$_FILES`

```
if(isset($_POST['order'])){
   $Input_File = $_FILES['file1'];
   $Input_File_Name = $Input_File['name'];
   $Input_File_type = $Input_File['type'];
   $Input_File_tmp_name = $Input_File['tmp_name'];
   $Input_File_size = $Input_File['size'];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! :)

Answer (score 4):

you are using multipart/form data but you are giving the file name field only. It will be used like that.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['order'])) {

    $file       =$_FILES['file1']['name'];


    echo $file;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `$_POST` to access the value of `<input type="file" />`.
You can access this by using `$_FILES`

try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
 $file = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
 echo $file;
}
?>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :D